# java socket multiple clients not receiving messages

Tags: java, sockets

i am making a java socket chat program and i made it compatible for multiple connections and when a user joins it doesn't send the message "[user] Joined" to all clients just to the one that connected but i have a thread for each client if anyone can tell me why it is only sending the message to the user that recently joined i would greatly appreciate it. Here is the server code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class server {
public ObjectInputStream input;
public ServerSocket server;
public Socket s;
public ObjectOutputStream output;
public ArrayList<Socket> users = new ArrayList<Socket>();
public class Accept implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(55555, 100);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(true) {
            try {
                s = server.accept();
                users.add(s);
                new EchoThread(s).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class EchoThread extends Thread {
    private Socket sock;
    public EchoThread(Socket s) throws IOException {
        this.sock = s;
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(sock.getInetAddress() + " Connected");
        try {
            for(Socket s: users) {
                output.writeObject(s.getInetAddress() + " Connected");
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
server() throws IOException {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Accept());
    t.start();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new server();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So,
Every time someone connects to the server, u create a new EchoThread.
Each User has his own EchoThread.

Your Server role is to manage all the EchoThreads and Sockets.

```
 output.writeObject(s.getInetAddress() + " Connected");
```

This only sends a message to ONE user.
Your Server should have a List of Sockets and send messages to every Sockets

```
public ArrayList<Socket> users = new ArrayList<Socket>();
public ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> outputs = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();


public class Accept implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(55555, 100);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true) {
            try {
                s = server.accept();
                users.add(s);
                outputs.add(new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));

                for (ObjectOutputStream o: outputs) {
                    o.writeObject(s.getInetAddress() + " has connected");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i added that to my code and it just sends the message to the user for how ever long the list is so if the list is 7 long it will send me the same msg 7 times

Comment: just a little error ^^
it is "s.getInetAdress", not socket.getInetAdress" :)

Comment: it still doesn't send the msg to all users

Comment: Yes, sorry, i have read to fast ^^ Your "output" is intenciated with the wrong Socket. "output = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());" And u shouldnt send messages to all the Users in the EchoThread class but in the Server class. Create a methode "sendMessage(String s)" in the Server class

Comment: you can also have an ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> in the Server

Comment: Wait, your "EchoThread" is my "sendMessage" method... I believe u dont need a Thread for sending messages. Thread is usefull here when u have a blocking method like "accept()"

Comment: ok thank you but do you know why i still need the EchoThread if it has nothing in it

Comment: Your dont need the EchoThread. Only if u want to send messages exactly at the same time, or maybe if a client disconnected u may get an error and the other users wont recieve the message. Well, u can keep your EchoThread and use it to send messages ^^ You have some work here to clear your code and make something beautifull :)

Comment: This doesn't work either. The loop needs to iterate over output streams, not sockets.

Comment: Yes, it depends how u manage your Server. i just edited my answer to make it simple.

Comment: sorry for asking to many questions but why did you put <ObjectOutputStream> at the end of the  ArrayList "outputs" instead of <Socket> like in the beginning?

Comment: I did both. Sockets represents a connected User, and OutputStream represent a stream ready to send data.

Comment: You meant `public ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> outputs = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();`.